# Setting color of individual cells in a GridPane (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, colors, tetris, gridpane

I'm making tetris for a class project, and I had the idea to utilize gridpane to divide the stage into evenly spaced rows and columns. I was going to change the color of each cell individually to simulate actual pieces, but I have no idea where to go from here. I tried adding colored rectangles, but that didn't work.

The colors are taken from a 2D array called colorArray that is 15X10, with a specific color at each index.

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    pane = new GridPane();
    pane.setGridLinesVisible(true);
    pane.setVgap(40);
    pane.setHgap(40);
    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    scene = new Scene(pane,height,width);
    for(int x = 0; x < 16; x++){
        pane.getRowConstraints().addAll(getFifteenRowConstraints());
        for(int y = 0; y<10; y++){
            pane.getColumnConstraints().addAll(getTenColumnConstraints());


        }
    }
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Russian Game");
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

I guess I'm not exactly sure what it is row and col constraints are, all I know is I have evenly placed cells that are separated by lines.

How would I go about changing the color of each cell individually?

Comment: You would set the style, or the background, of the nodes that you add to the grid pane. You cannot set the colors with the row or column constraints.

Comment: Perhaps take a look at this [sample code for a color chooser](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/2030464) (which is a styled grid).  It is probably not directly applicable to your problem, but may give you some ideas of how you might proceed with your development.

Comment: Just fill every cell of gridpane with nice node to represent the "empty cell". This node could be as simple as a Label with white background. Then access these labels and change colors of them.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Rectangle class in JavaFX. Here is an example of a Rectangle being drawn black in JavaFX.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Driver extends Application {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Group group = new Group();

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(20,20,200,200);

    rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    group.getChildren().add(rect);

    Scene scene = new Scene(group, 300, 200);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
  }
}
```